# how to use semantics ui components with out wrting additional jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I am using semantics ui. For example if I want to use dropdown component I should call the function in my script tag. like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.dropdown')
    .dropdown()
  ;
</script>
```

Is there any way you know to stop writing additional script.Like bootstrap and others do it.

Answer (score 0):

Many of Semantic UI's modules have versions that can be created without the use of javascript, but they will have limited functionality or a very crude design.

You will need to dig through the documentation to find the equivalent for each module. For example, [Dropdown](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html) has both without javascript and [simple](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#simple) versions.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#firstDropdown').dropdown();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="ui header">With Javascript</div>
<select id="firstDropdown">
  <option value="">Select ...</option>
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>

<div class="ui header">Without Javascript</div>
<select id="secondDropdown" class="ui selection dropdown">
  <option value="">Select ...</option>
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>

<div class="ui header">
  Simple Dropdown
  <div class="sub header">Does not require javascript to initialise, but will require it to handle selection &amp; behaviour</div>
</div>
<div class="ui compact menu">
  <div class="ui simple dropdown item">
    Dropdown
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item">Choice 1</div>
      <div class="item">Choice 2</div>
      <div class="item">Choice 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```